# Jenkins does not accept variable declaration

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am trying to start a docker image from Jenkins.
([Not getting Docker to run from within Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219276/not-getting-docker-to-run-from-within-jenkins))
I think I'm really close but this part has still some issues.
Can please anyone help?

```
    stage('build Dockerimage 1') {
      steps{
        apitestimage = docker.build('apitestimage', '--no-cache=true dockerbuild')
      }
    }

    stage('start Dockerimage and Tests 2') {
      steps{
        apitestimage.inside {
          sh 'cd testing && ctest'           
        }
      }
    }
```

Jenkins reports:
WorkflowScript: 21: Expected a step @ line 21, column 15. apitestimage = docker.build('apitestimage', '--no-cache=true dockerbuild')

and also

WorkflowScript: 27: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 27, column 13. apitestimage.inside {

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From your error, it shows that you're missing a `script` block in your steps. You'll need a script block when using the DSL in `steps`.

```
stage('build Dockerimage 1') {
  steps{
    script {
      def apitestimage = docker.build('apitestimage', '--no-cache=true dockerbuild')
    }
  }
}

stage('start Dockerimage and Tests 2') {
  steps{
    script {
      apitestimage.inside {
        sh 'cd testing && ctest'
      }           
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

- https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I did declare a variable using the `stages` name: `def stages = [buildStage]`

Changing this variable name to another name fixed my issue.